# XPath: extract element nodes before/after substring

Tags: xpath

I have an XML file which basically is a list of entry elements:

```
...
<entry> Lorem ipsum <name n="1">dolor</name> sit amet, <name n="2">consectetur</name> adipiscing
    elit, XXXXX sed do <name n="3">eiusmod</name> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. YYYYY Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis <name n="3">nostrud</name> exercitation ullamco
    laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</entry>
...
```

Each entry element has text with an arbitrary number of name elements. The text of each entry is split in three sections by the strings XXXXX and YYYYY. I'd like to access the name elements as three distinct lists:

1. all names of section I (from start of text to XXXXX)
2. all names of section II (from XXXXX to YYYYY)
3. all names of section III (from YYYYY to end of text)

My first instinct for 1. was to split the string at XXXXX, and look into results for extracting the name nodes, but `//entry/tokenize(string(), "XXXXX")` returns a list of strings, without the name nodes.
Is there any Xpath expression to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Also, given the sample xml in the question, what exactly (not a description, but exactly) is your expected output?